# Vuetify v-chip with both BORDER and BACKGROUND

Tags: vuetify.js

You'd think it is easily doable. Yet...

**v-chip outlined class="mystyle"** ignores the background colour setting

**v-chip class="mystyle"** ignores the border setting

(mystyle's css specifies background and border params)

Has it not occurred to anyone that we may want both AT THE SAME TIME??? :-)

Comment: You may simply need a custom CSS class for this, perhaps utilizing CSS variable for the actual color(s) of the background and/or border. If you can't achieve something out of the box with Vuetify - it's certainly a time to begin writing some custom CSS.

Comment: ok, I gave more details in that the CSS is specified, but it is overriden by vue